# when I declare the variable global and use it in another function it shows this error NameError: name 'img_file' is not defined

Tags: python, function

In this code, I am writing a function to get the images only from the folder which contains a corresponding txt file, so when i use the declared variable in another function it shows error

is it because the global variable is inside a loop?

```
import os

def open_image():
  global img_file
  EXT = ['.jpeg','.png','.jpg']
  path = os.getcwd()
  mydir = os.listdir(path)
  for i in mydir:
    k = os.path.splitext(i)
    if k[1] in EXT:
      img_file = k[0]+k[1]

def image():
  print(img_file)

image()
```

Comment: it is the wrong usage of `global`. Add at script level `img_file` (in your case should be a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call open_image() funciton where global variable is declared .

```
import os

def open_image():
  global img_file
  EXT = ['.jpeg','.png','.jpg']
  path = os.getcwd()
  mydir = os.listdir(path)
  for i in mydir:
    k = os.path.splitext(i)
    if k[1] in EXT:
      img_file = k[0]+k[1]
open_image()
def image():
  print(img_file)

image()
```

Comment: It's much better to have all the definitions first, and the two function calls at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Declare img_file in a global scope by moving it out of your function. Call open_image to populate the list and thecall the image() function to print it.
Or call the open_image in the image function, whatever fits your use-case

```
import os

img_file=[]

def open_image():
  EXT = ['.jpeg','.png','.jpg']
  path = os.getcwd()
  mydir = os.listdir(path)
  for i in mydir:
    k = os.path.splitext(i)
    if k[1] in EXT:
      img_file.append(k[0]+k[1])

def image():
  print(img_file)

open_image()
image()
```

Comment: this does give me the list of images, is there a way to display the image from a list? sorry if this seems like an odd question I am new to python

Comment: which image to you want to display? By image name or index? And by display image you mean open it as in "open in an image viewer"?

Comment: by image name, by displaying I mean just reading it like using the cv2.imread

Comment: i wrote the code that displays from the list thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Python:
to use a local variable inside of another function we use func

```
def func():
  func.name = "Ali Axghar"

func()
print(func.name)
```

**Output**: Ali Axghar

Comment: have you tried the code? That's a function attribute and you do not define it like that!